# C++ template parameter pack automatically adds & to its parameters

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, packaged-task

Check the below code.

```
#include <future>

template <class F, class... Args>
void do_something(F f, Args... args) {
    using return_type = typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type;

    // Why below gives an error?
    std::packaged_task<return_type(Args...)> task(f, args...);
}

int func(int a, int b) {

}
int main() {
    do_something(func, 1, 2);
}
```

The `packaged_task` constructor gives a following error.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::packaged_task<int(int, int)>::packaged_task(int (*&)(int, int), int&, int&)'

8 |     std::packaged_task<return_type(Args...)> task(f, args...);
```

The thing I don't understand is that why `f` and `args` became a reference type in the constructor? The `Args...` were `int, int` types whereas `args...` just became `int&, int&`. Where is this coming from?

Comment: I realized that the packaged_task takes only a function as an argument :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[packaged_task](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/packaged_task) do not have the signature you want.

compiler is saying there is no such function. (probably with candidates below it)